# Spinner Not Showing using BehaviorSubject and async

Tags: angular, spinner, behaviorsubject

I have the following service to accommodate for a global spinner in my app:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
  private visible = new BehaviorSubject < boolean > (true);

  showSpinner() {
    this.visible.next(true);
  }

  hideSpinner() {
    this.visible.next(false);
  }

  getSpinnerVisibility(): Observable < boolean > {
    return this.visible.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Then the following just above my `router-outlet` in my main app component:

`<app-spinner *ngIf="spinnerService.getSpinnerVisibility() | async"></app-spinner>`

But `spinnerService.showSpinner()` does not actually trigger it to be shown; any idea why? I have declared `SpinnerService` in the `providers` array of my `AppModule`.

Here's the spinner component:

`<div class="backdrop"><div class="spinner"></div></div>`

There's absolutely nothing else to it! And when I remove the `*ngIf` statement above, it displays correctly by the way, which means there's nothing wrong with the CSS.

Comment: What does your `app-spinner` component looks like?

Comment: Having never used an `async` pipe with a `Subject` of any type nor on an `ngIf` condition I'd be suspect to the concept working. Have you tried wiring up a subscription to a basic boolean property to at least confirm that part of the concept?  Is your core purpose here as a "loading" spinner perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the concept is simply a loader. Ok, I'll try wiring to a basic subscribe/unsubscribe with a Boolean and see.

Comment: It should work. Please create a plunker

Comment: I failed to create a plunker for this :(
I did change it to a normal subscribe though, and it worked. I also noticed that when it's a normal subscribe, I see this in the Chrome inspector:
`<!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": false }-->`
But when I use the async pipe, the `false` becomes `null`

Answer (score 0):

I've put toghter something who can resemble your example ( but I'm not sure how your spinner component looks like ) and i didn't used the | async pipe but i just return the Behaviour subject as Observable ( i think in this case is safe enough also using just the typings )

```
isLoading(): Observable<boolean> {
return this._loadingState;
}
```

this is the plunker with the solution.

http://plnkr.co/edit/bYG9IEsIow24zfvxQOKT